# Broadcast' object has no attribute 'destroy'?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-1.6

In my pyspark scirpt code, I declare a Broadcast variable. At last, I want to destory this variable, but get

> Blockquote
>   AttributeError: 'Broadcast' object has no attribute 'destroy'

My code like this：

```
br = sc.broadcast(my_value)
rdd.map(__my_map_function) # __my_map_function() used br variable
br.destroy()
```

My spark version is 1.6.1, and I know the class BroadCast has the destroy() method, but Why the code throw this exception? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `destroy` method wasn't available in pyspark before **spark-2.x**.

You could check out [the sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/python/pyspark/broadcast.py) when in doubt.